# Urllib2 response .read() is empty even though response is not

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to make a simple HTTPS request with basic authentication like so:

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://myurl")
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic {0}".format(auth_token))
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = json.loads(resp.read())
```

I am getting a 200 response but `body` is always an empty string, even if I call `resp.read()` multiple times. Seems like it would be a server issue but I confirmed that the content-length header is non-zero and then even captured the request in Fiddler and verified the response is non-empty and contains the JSON I expect to be there. I have tried `readline` and `readlines` with similar results. If I purposely screw with my auth token the response is 401 instead, so I don't think that's the issue.

Any theories as to why this may be, or tips to debug further?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was able to fix it by splitting up the last line into two:

```
resp_body = resp.read()
content = json.loads(resp.read())
```

Can consistently reproduce/fix the issue by flipping back and forth between the two. Unless I am misunderstanding something fundamental, this must be a bug in Python 2.7.3.